# What is the right way to ask these questions?

Tags: word-order, questions, in-situ-wh-questions

Sentences:

> 1) What **Ann did** make? or "What **did Ann** make?" or "What **Ann made**?"
>
> 2) "When **was it** raining?" or "When **it was** raining?"
>
> 3) "Whose **dog did Ann** approach?" or "Whose **dog Ann** approached?"

What is the right way to ask these questions?

Comment: Max, this is too many questions at once. We're here to help you understand concepts, not necessarily to answer every single example question you can come up with. - So, think about the underlying concept that you're not understanding and ask a question about that.  Even as is, without knowing what you want to say in each situation, we can't always answer. Sometimes, both sentences are possible but they mean different things... and neither of the options in the fifth example make sense.

Comment: @CatijaI haven't known that I could use either option. I want to know about the usage of each option (if both of them are possible). Would you please describe these cases. 
**The main point of the question is to become aware when and how to use auxiliary verbs**

Comment: @CatijaI I've just divided this question into two separated questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what way should I ask the question in terms of word order?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124898/in-what-way-should-i-ask-the-question-in-terms-of-word-order)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What did Ann make?

and

> When was it raining?

and

> Whose dog did Ann approach?

Generally, *in these situations* the (intransitive) verb comes before the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

In a question, the first auxiliary verb normally precedes its subject. If it doesn't have one, you need to use a form of *DO* (usually called a *do-suppport*).

So the correct versions are:

1. What did Ann make?
2. When was it raining?
3. Whose dog did Ann approach?

The other versions are only used if the questions are subordinate (embedded)—when they are indirectly stated in another sentence.

> I don't know **what Ann made**.

It's also possible to use *DO*, but it's rather emphatic.

> I don't know **what Ann did make.**(Note that the DO follows the subject).