# What the right way of using auxiliary verb in these sentences?

Tags: word-order, questions, in-situ-wh-questions

Sentences:

> 1) "Whose **dog did bite** him?" or "Whose **dog bit** him?"
>
> 2) "Whose children **did man organize** the celebration for?" or "Whose children **man organized** the celebration for?" *(Man organized the celebration for children. The question about defining children)*

What is the right way to ask these questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to ask these questions?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127695/what-is-the-right-way-to-ask-these-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whose dog bit him?

and

> Whose children did **the** man organize the celebration for?

although you may get yelled at for ending your sentence with a preposition.

Comment: ...and not showing any research, or which you think is wrong and why.

Comment: @Stephen S Thanks a lot for your help. Is it more appropriate way of asking? **_FOR_ whose children did the man organize the celebration?**

Comment: @Max that is formally correct, though I would use the one ending in "for" myself (and probably get yelled at for it).

Comment: @Max and Stephen S: I'd suggest rather "*may* get yelled at"; sensible grammarians do not worry about this particular rule, as even highly literate and eloquent native speakers don't bother to follow it reliably.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yeah, it's a general axiom that everyone spouts but fewer actually follow. Still good to have out there on a site like this though.

Comment: I do think it's good to let learners know of its existence, but ideally also let them know that it's not actually that big a deal.